# Is there any alternative to the insight debugger for lubuntu?

Tags: assembly

Could you please tell me if there is any alternative to the **insight
debugger** or how to run and debug assembly code from Jeff Duntemann's Assembly Language Step by Step 3rd edition with a debugger where output
would be the same as the output depicted in the examples shown in the book?
I'm a total noob in assembly planning to learn it so this book has been recommended to me but the debugger insight is no longer supported by ubuntu that I've been using for a long time. I tried to compile the source from insight site but make failed and it doesn't seem to be an easy job

Comment: gdb is not bad for asm.  Use `layout asm` / `layout reg`, as suggested at the bottom of the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: Thank you. There are many topics on asm on the page but I found the last topic and ran gdb with tui + the layouts mentioned. I've never seen/used gdb with sub-windows like that. Amazing! I'll try with the code 'n hopefully it'll work.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was pretty cool when I discovered it.  That's why I thought it was worth adding to the tag wiki :P.   There are some real graphical debuggers that run on Linux, but I haven't used them.  I also haven't tried LLDB (part of the LLVM project, so it's a lot newer than gdb.  IDK if it's better or not for asm, and I already know how to use gdb).

Comment: Related [Setup insight on Ubuntu 14.04 or Linux Mint 17](//stackoverflow.com/q/26190094) has some answers that may get an actual working Insight debugger on modern Linux.  (not a duplicate because this is asking for an *alternative*.)